# How can I get an exclusively element's font size and not inherited font size by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

`$(this).css('font-size')` gives inherited font size as well.
How can I get font-size that is declared only for that element and is not inherited?

Comment: What do you mean "as well"? I just tried it on the page for `.post-text` and it just returned `14px`

Comment: It returns inherited font size if font size for that element is not present.I want font size if it is declared for that element, not the inherited font-size.

Comment: Your declared font-size has been override? why you need to get it?

Comment: I am trying to increase font size through jquery of each element on the page.Jquery increases the font size of parent and it again increases the font size of element inheriting the font size of parent.Hence the font-size of parent is increamented twice.

Comment: if you want to get the font-size you defined, maybe you should add important in the style, then you can get it from jquery

Comment: I need to check if font size is declared for an element or is it inheriting it from parent.

Comment: compare to parent font size is about the best you can do